# How to translate all objects from it's data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get some data from an api, then from that data i build my items in DOM, each item has a description which is get in different languages from the API.

I have a variable which is set with the current choosen language like `it, de, en etc...`

the object has the folliwing structure:

```
{ id: "001", desc: { it: "Ciao", en: "Hello", fr: "Hellous", de: "Hei", es: "Hola", ru: "Привет" }
```

Then when i create my DOM object i set a data attribute like `data-trans-api` where i set the whole `desc`

So my object looks like this:

```
  $("<a>", {
    class: "flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link",
  })
    .attr("data-toggle", "pill")
    .attr("href", `#tab_${menu.id}`) //added text
    .attr("aria-controls", "tab_" + menu.id) //added text
    .attr("role", "tab")
    .data("trans-api", menu.desc)
    .attr("aria-selected", "false")
    .text(menu.desc[lang])
```

Then i have a function which yet translate all static content from my array of languages which looks like this:

```
function changeLanguage(language) {
  lang = language;
  $("[data-trans]").each(function () {
    let text = $(this).data("trans");
    if (text === "articoli") {
      var qtaProdotti = $(".prodotto").length;
      $("#countProdotti").text(
        qtaProdotti === 1
          ? qtaProdotti + " " + arrLang[language]["articolo"]
          : qtaProdotti + " " + arrLang[language]["articoli"]
      );
    } else {
      $(this).html([arrLang[language][text]]);
    }
  });
}
```

How can i add to it even the translation of the objects created from the API?

Comment: Try `$("[data-trans], [data-trans-api]")`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc in the function which set the translation to data-trans the translation is get from a JSON object it's a different structure than data-trans-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and parse the object stored in `data-trans-api` first then change text of the element depend on this object and the language passed.

```
function changeLanguage(language) {
  // Your current code
  lang = language;
  $("[data-trans]").each(function () {
    ...
  });

  // New code to handle objects created from the API
  $("[data-trans-api]").each(function () {
    let desc = JSON.parse($(this).data(trans-api));
    $(this).text(desc[language])
  });
}
```